# Binomial response in piecewiseSEM

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, structural-equation-modeling

I have data from an agricultural field trial with scouting data (pest infestation, leaf damage estimates) on two occasions and plant height and yield at harvest. There are six field management treatments including the control, and the trial has a split plot design with farmers' fields (=block), nested within landscapes with different levels of tree cover, nested within districts with different levels of rainfall. There are 15 farmers per landscape, 2 landscapes per district and 6 districts. The dataset is also unbalanced because of farmers dropping out or missed data collections.

For the scouting, a sample 50 plants were surveyed per treatment plot with pest infestation assessed as present/absent and leaf damage assessed on a 0-8 scale (the plants sampled were different from the first and second scouting). At harvest all plants in the plot were measured for height and the plot level yield was calculated. Hence, each dataset is a separate sample from the same treatment plot and raw data tables have different lengths. I summarised my data by treatment plot, as follows;

```
data_sum <- data %>%
    group_by(district, landscape, farmer_name, treatment) %>%
    summarise(
        pest_Y_early = sum(pest_early),
        pest_N_early = 50-sum(pest_early),
        leaf_damage_early = mean(leaf_damage_early),
        pest_Y_late = sum(pest_late),
        pest_N_late = 50-sum(pest_late),
        leaf_damage_late = mean(leaf_damage_late),
        plant_height = mean(plant_height),
        grain_yield = grain_yield)
```

A binomial model for early pest infestation can be specified as follows;

```
glmer(cbind(pest_Y_early, pest_N_early) ~ district + landscape + treatment + (1 | district/landscape/farmer_name), family = "binomial", na.action = na.omit, data = data_sum)
```

and one for leaf damage, as follows;

```
glmer(leaf_damage ~ district + landscape + treatment + pest_Y_early + (1 | district/landscape/farmer_name), family = "poisson", na.action = na.omit, data = data_sum)
```

and similar models can be specified for the other endogenous variables. However, when I try to specify a psem I run into problems and it generates an error. I considered specifying different datasets for each of the component models using the raw data, but this runs into problems because the datasets are different lengths. I also tried specifying the binomial response as a proportion and using the "weights = " option, but the problem is the same.

I would be grateful if someone could suggest a solution.